# PHP decision making based on MySQL query output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to use a query output in `if` statement in `MySQL`. Script should run a query, which counts specified rows in database table and depends on this number make decision, which another query should run which parameters.
A sample query, which gives back a number:

```
SELECT count(case when studentid='$studentid' AND classid='$classid' AND endsig is NULL then 1 end) as p
FROM signature
```

How can I handle query output `p` variable in PHP script or use it up in `if` statements?

Comment: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at mysql_result() function.

Answer (score -1):

You could reformat it to:

```
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM signature WHERE studentid='$studentid' AND classid'$classid' AND endsig is NULL");
$p = mysqli_num_rows($q);
```

Then you can use $p as your number, for instance

```
if($p == 1) {
    echo "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: As I think it cannot provides exact return value.